# importing spring configuration and exclude filters

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring context that does @ComponentScan.

I'd like to add a variation of my configuration that excludes certain beans either by package name or a regex. I am aware of using @Import to import other configurations.

But, could I import a configuration and override its component scannign by doing an exclusion filter? Will this work?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = { "my.app.pack1", "my.app.pack2" })
public class ClientApplicationConfig {}



@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = { "my.app.pack1" },
  excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern = "my.app.pack1.ignore.*"))
    public class DifferentClientAppConfig {}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I wouldn't expect it, as both component scans will lead to detected components, they aren't merged.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. For instance, try the following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value={"my.app.pack1"},excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.CUSTOM,value=MainConfig.WebExclude.class))
public class MainConfig
{
  public static class WebExclude extends RegexPatternTypeFilter{

    public WebExclude(Pattern aPattern)
    {
      super(Pattern.compile("my.app.pack1\\.ignore"));
    }
...
```

You can give it whatever regex you want. This will component scan my.app.pack1 excluding my.app.pack1.ignore.*